# ¿Cual es la anotacion para poder asignarle un alias a mi variable dentro de mi clase?

Tags: java, spring

He creado una clase que mapea los campos que me trae una consulta usando mybatis. 
Pero quiero que en el archivo .xml del mapper los campos tienen unos nombres distintos y en mi clase .java otros nombres. Por eso quisiera saber si hay alguna anotacion que le asigne un alias a mis variables.

```py
package pe.com.abc.harec.repository.output;

public class ObtenerRequerimientoResponse {
    //anotacion para asignar un alias
    private String numero;

    private String resumen;

    private String codigo;
}
```

y este es mi archivo .xml

```sql
SELECT 
            REQ.NUMERO AS NUM,
            REQ.RESUMEN AS RES_PROD,
            TIPO.NOMBRE AS COD_PROD,

FROM 
            REQ_REQUERIMIENTO REQ
```

Comment: no usas algun orm?

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar @column, ejemplo:

```
@Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

Comment: x-rw probe con esa anotacion pero al parecer no lo esta reconociendo como nombre de la variable